# How to create a folder (with subfolders) with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

Filemaker has the ability to ake use of AppleScript.

From within Filemaker I want to create a new folder (with the name of a FileMaker field) that holds 6 subfolders.

I am a complete noob where it comes to Applescript.

This is my script so far:

```
tell application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
set folder_name to cell "FolderName" of current record
end tell
tell application "Finder"
     activate
     make new folder at folder "Desktop" of folder "dick" of folder "Users" of startup disk with properties {name:folder_name}
end tell
tell application "Finder"
     activate
        make new folder at folder {name:folder_name} of folder "Desktop" of folder "dick" of folder "Users" of startup disk with properties {name:"subfolder"}
end tell
```

My problem is: the creation of "Subfolder1"

What is my mistake there?

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you crate a new folder you can define various properties, but when refering to the folder just use the name, for example:

```
make new folder at folder folder_name of folder "Desktop" of folder "dick" of folder "Users" of startup disk with properties {name:"subfolder"}
```

Note that the result returned from making a new folder is a reference to that folder, so you can also do something like:

```
tell application "Finder"

  set newFolder to (make new folder at folder "Desktop" of folder "dick" of folder "Users" of startup disk with properties {name:folder_name})

  make new folder at newFolder with properties {name:"subfolder"}

end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

```
set myPath to POSIX path of ((path to desktop as text) & folder_name & ":subfolder")
do shell script "mkdir -p " & myPath
```